# Xcode 12: how to show the status bar in storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, statusbar, xcode12

There is no `Status bar` setting anymore in Xcode 12 `Simulated metrics`, when editing a storyboard.

[image: Xcode View Controller attributes]

My layouts are off (different from what the simulator renders) in Interface Builder because it does not display the status bar.

[image: Storyboard without status bar]

**Is there a way to force Xcode to show the status bar?**

If not, is there an easy workaround, like creating a fake status bar view with a placeholder constraint (to be removed at build time)?

Comment: It's not clear what's the problem is, after reading: "My layouts are off (different from what the simulator renders) in Interface Builder because it does not display the status bar."

Comment: I mean that the absolute vertical position of my views is wrong in IB. In the simulator, my top view has a Y coordinate of about 40pts (because of the status bar height), whereas in IB the same view is laid out at about Y:10pts.